# Permanent redirect across HTTP methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, routes

I have the following couple of methods in my `CommentsController`.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult New(long id)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Posts", new { id }); // lets be graceful.
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult New(long id, string comment, IMiniPrincipal principal)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Both are resolved through any `posts/{id}/comment` route where id is a numeric value. I added the `GET` action mostly to avoid confusion (instead of just telling the user it doesn't exist when they attempt to access the route manually instead of through a form `POST`, I redirect them to the post the comment would've been submitted to).

The question is whether I can use a Permanent Redirect result in HTTP GET requests and still not get permanently redirected during HTTP POST requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permanent redirect works on a per-method basis, so you can actually perform a permanent redirect on a `POST` to a given url, while serving content on `GET` requests to the same url.

Comment: Answer I was looking for, but 1) where is this specified and 2) can I trust browsers they will work like this?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off having your POST handler map to a model, which should make it much less likely that the same URL maps to both actions.

So your code might change to something like:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult New(CommentModel model)
{
    // { ...code... }
}
```

With the model looking something like:

```
public class CommentModel
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public IMiniPrincipal Principal { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've added the `HttpGet` action intentionally, in order to redirect users manually requesting that route to the actual post instead of a 404 page.

Comment: With the attributes you've specified, your actions will only map to the method matching the request type. So even if you POST something like `/posts/42/comment`, it will only map to the method adorned with the `[HttpPost]` attribute. So... you should be fine as-is. Of course, the example I just mentioned would probably result in a 404...

Comment: yeah, I don't think you got the part where I want to redirect to `posts/42` instead of 404ing when the user `GET`s `posts/42/comment`